# @Font-Face not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, fonts

im just confused why my codes in css are not working.
im using codeigniter for this project.

i have a font called 'Viner Hand ITC' i put all the formats in my root with a sub folder called 'font' but its not working.

just check this out.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "Viner Hand ITC";
        src: url('font/435028077-27990.eot');
        src: url('font/435028077-27990.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font/435028077-27990.svg#Viner Hand ITC') format('svg'),
        url('font/435028077-27990.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font/435028077-27990.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

body {
        background : #000!important;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: justify;
        font-family: "Viner Hand ITC"!important;
        direction: ltr;
}
```

but when i open my page it always using the default font..

Comment: Where is your CSS file in relation to the root? Unless the CSS file is directly inside the root folder, your paths are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

font-family with src attribute not support in many Browser. Check your Browser.